# Autosizing different sized images in a single row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a set of images that are different heights, widths, and aspect ratios. I'd like to line them all up to fit across the screen. I also want the heights to all be the same. So I can set the width to auto and manually play with the height until no images drop down to the next line, but obviously that doesn't work across monitors with different resolutions than mine. Is there an easy way to do this without having to use any constants of the specific images?

Answer (score 0):

If you set `img {max-width: 100%}` your images will become responsive and scale nicelly across different resolutions. Then you have to set `height: 100%` or some other percentage value and your images should look good and equal across different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="IMAGE LINK" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">`

try using this to make your image responsive to all displays.

Note: It may affect the ratios